# Back button in standalone UINavigationBar with UINavigationController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying to implement a push-up UINavigationBar, where the position of the navigation bar is attached to the contentOffset of the UIScrollView (similar to how safari works in ios7).

In order to get the dynamic movement working I am using a UINavigationBar created programatically and added as a subview of the UIViewController's `view` (it is accessible as `self.navbar`).

The UIViewController is within a UINavigationController hierarchy, so I am hiding the built-in `self.navigationController.navigationBar` at the top of `-viewWillAppear:`.

The problem I am trying to solve is to add a back button to this new standalone navbar. I would preferably like to simply copy the buttons or even the navigationItems from the navigationController and its hidden built-in navbar, but this doesnt seem to work

Is my only solution to set leftBarButtonItem on my standalone navbar to be a fake back button (when there is a backItem in the navController's navbar)? This seems a bit hacky, and I'd rather use the built backButton functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to do that, once you have your own `UINavigationBar` set, is to *push* two `UINavigationItems` on your navigationBar, causing back button to appear. You can then customize what happens when the back button is pressed.

Here's how I did that

1 - Some `UINavigationItem` subclass, to define extra-behavior / customization parameters

```
@interface MyNavigationItem : UINavigationItem

//example : some custom back action when 'back' is pressed
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^onBackClickedAction)(void);

@end
```

2 - Then wire that into your `UINavigationBarDelegate` :

```
- (BOOL)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar shouldPopItem:(UINavigationItem *)item
{
    if ([item isKindOfClass:[MyNavigationItem class]]) {
        MyNavigationItem *navItem = (MyNavigationItem *)item;


        //custom action
        if (navItem.backAction) {
            navItem.backAction();
        }
        return YES;// return NO if you don't want your bar to animate to previous item
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

You could adapt that scheme, calling your UINavigationController **pop** method on back action.
This is still hacky

Comment: Neat idea, I'll try it. Where are you pushing the UINavigationItems - in viewWillAppear:? My way of figuring out if there should be a back button is if self.navigationController.viewControllers.count > 1 (and getting the title from the count-1 ViewController)... are you doing something similar?

Comment: No, My UINavigationBar isn't in my content UIViewController, but in its container parent. In your case, you might move your UINavigationBar into your UINavigationController subclass

Comment: I don't have a UINavigationController subclass. The push-up navbar only used for a specific class of UIViewController (a list). In fact I am navigating to a viewcontroller that goes back to using the standard navigation bar (static content). And I need to be able to navigate between list->list or list->static->list. So to me it makes sense for the list ViewController to own and manage the navbar.

Comment: So far it is mostly working, but I cannot get the back button to be clickable and to trigger a popItem event (strangely it does trigger a pop with a swipe to the right). Any ideas?

Comment: Just to note, the lack of clickability was an issue with my implementation of the navigation bar (I was adding a colored subview to intensify the color, but userInteraction was enabled :P)

Comment: This works beautifully, no assumptions, no fear for breakage.

Answer (score 1):

Vinzzz' answer was a good solution. Here is my implementation, as the context was slightly different.

In the UIViewController's `viewDidLoad` method I setup my navbar's navigation items like this:

```
NSMutableArray* navItems = [@[] mutableCopy];
if (self.navigationController.viewControllers.count > 1)
{
    NSInteger penultimateIndex = (NSInteger)self.navigationController.viewControllers.count - 2;
    UIViewController* prevVC =  (penultimateIndex >= 0) ? self.navigationController.viewControllers[penultimateIndex] : nil;

    UINavigationItem* prevNavItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];
    prevNavItem.title = prevVC.title;

    [navItems addObject:prevNavItem];
}

UINavigationItem* currNavItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];

... <Add any other left/right buttons to the currNavItem> ...

[navItems addObject:currNavItem];
[self.navbar setItems:navItems];
```

...where `self.navbar` is my floating stand-alone UINavigationBar.

I also assign the current view controller to be `self.navbar`'s delegate, and then listen for the `-navigationBar:shouldPopItem:` event that is triggered when the back button is pressed:

```
- (BOOL)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar shouldPopItem:(UINavigationItem *)item
{
    if (navigationBar == self.navbar)
    {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

(If you return `YES`, it will crash when a swipe gesture is used in ios7).